# El Gamal encryption variant and its security

Tags: elgamal-encryption, semantic-security

We are given an El Gamal variant and are requested to find the decryption scheme and the security of the encryption. The variant operates on a group $\mathbb{G}$ of prime order q and g, h are two generators of the group $\mathbb{G}$ (the relation between g and h is unknown). The key generation and encryption are the following:

$KGen(λ) \rightarrow  (sk, pk) = (x, g^x)$, where $x$ is chosen randomly from $\mathbb{Z}_q^*$

$Enc(pk, m) \rightarrow ({pk}^r, g^r h^m)$, where $r$ is chosen randomly from $\mathbb{Z}_q^*$

As for the decryption, it is pretty obvious to me that the decryption scheme is as follows:
$Dec(x, Enc(pk, m)) = (pk^r)^{-1}(g^rh^m)^x = g^{-xr}g^{rx}h^{mx} = (h^x)^{m}$

I know that $h^x$ is known by the person with the secret key, but in order to retrieve the message $m$, that person would have to compute $log_{h^x}((h^x)^{m})$, which is a hard problem. Is this acceptable? Is there an other way that I may be missing?

After that, it is requested to check for OW-CPA, IND-CPA, IND-CCA security. Again, what am I hoping to find here? That an adversary can distinguish $h^{xm_0}$ from $h^{xm_1}$ or that the adversary can distinguish $m_0$ from $m_1$? If it is the latter, then of course nobody can solve the discrete log problem and the scheme is secure, but I do not think this is the case. Would really appreciate some help, as I was not able to find anything relevant online.

Comment: "have to compute $log_{h^x}((h^x)^{m})$, which is a hard problem"; actually, if the decryptor knows aprior that $0 \le m < n$, he can recover $m$ in $O(\sqrt{n})$ time.  That means that encoding 20 bit values would be practical, and even 40 bit values would be plausible...

Comment: I get that, but even in elliptic curves (witch are the safest) $n$ is 256 bit (due to the existence of these types of attacks). So is this really acceptable?

Comment: Actually, what I denoted as $n$ is not the order of the curve (which, as you state, is large), but the maximum value of the secret.  For example, if you use a 256 bit elliptic curve to pass a 20 bit secret, we have $n=2^{20}$.  I supposed should have picked a different variable here to denote the secret size...